# XOR, MD5 and Base64 encoding issue

Tags: encoding, base64, md5, xor

i need to get value which first 16 characters are **TZxy2o2h2I2NMVR+** for which I have a formula. The formula goes like this: `Base64(XOR("KonstantaZaLDAP", MD5(521009)) + XOR(521009, "KonstantaZaLDAP"))` or in a word:

I have two values:

1. `int radID = 521009`
2. `String konst = "KonstantaZaLDAP"`

The first step is to apply XOR operation to konst and MD5 hash value of konst >>`XOR(kost, MD5(radID))`

Second, I need to apply XOR operation to radID and konst >> `XOR(radID, konst)`.

After that i should concatenate values from first and second step >> `XOR(kost, MD5(radID)) + XOR(radID, konst)` and finaly Base64 encode concatenated value. 
That is `Base64(XOR(konst, MD5(radID)) + XOR(radID, konst))`.

I have tried to achieve wanted value, and whatever I do, I get first 13 characters right, and after that it's all wrong. The value I get is **TZxy2o2h2l2NMfUfpPmJNA==**

Can anyone help!?